# Hibernate query: positioned parameter and named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

There are two types of query parameters binding in the Hibernate Query. One is positioned parameter and another one is named parameter.

Can I use these two parameters in one Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't think so, if you try it, hibernate you give you the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: cannot define positional parameter after any named parameters have been defined
```

Why would you want to do that?

Edit: Jeshurun offers a much better solution. Please check his answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Sure you can, as long as you make sure all positional parameters precede any named parameters. Heres an example:

```
    Query q =session.createQuery("select u from User u where u.location=? and u.id in (:user_ids)");
    q.setParameter(0, location);
    q.setParameterList("user_ids", userIds);
    return q.list();
```